# Try to fetch a data by code or using WHERE condition. But it returns nothing when getting the data

Tags: node.js, sql-server, angular, typescript

I'm running the project Angular using Node.js server MSSQL express.  Can someone please check my code what is missing or mistake in getting the data using WHERE condition. Thank you.

/// Backend server API node.js MSSQL

```
checkCustPhone: (phone, callback) => {
    connection.query(
      `select * from tbl_customers where Phone_Number='${phone}'`,
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null, result);
      }
    );
  }

    custData: (req, res) => {
    let phone = req.phone;
    checkCustPhone(req.params.phone,(error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.send({ status: 0, data: result.recordset });
      }
      return res.send({ status: 1, data: result.recordset });
    });
  }

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

  const {
  custData,
    } = require("./Tcontroller");
    router.get("/getcustomer", custData);
```

// Service.ts

```
 getCustomerData(Phone_Number: any) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/orders/getcustomer`,Phone_Number);
  }
```

/// Component.ts

```
 Phone_Number = '9762985657';

    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.orderService.getCustomerData(this.Phone_Number).subscribe((res: any) => {
         console.log(res.data); }, 
        (error) => {
              this.alertService.onError(error.message);
          });
       }
```

I'm testing in console log in my Component to check if I get data using a Phone Number from the DB but it returns nothing.

Comment: If you run the equivalent query in SSMS, do you get data back?

Comment: Yes using this phone number 9762985657...

Comment: mssql lib could have switched to promises
``` async (phone, cb) => {
    connection.query( ).then(cb)```

Comment: @nerkn Hi, can you please give me the exact code here.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

From the response to your previous comment, you get a response when you run the phone number query against your backend db. Which is a great start.

Here are few errors I see on the angular side of your code.

1. Incorrect request in your service.ts
   you're not passing the `phone` as a parameter in the request.the backend is expecting a `phone` as req.params. that is in your `checkCustPhone(....).  Without passing in the` phone` as parameter through your service, your BE won't receive any phone as req.params to check your db against and return a results.

Modify your service.ts to include the phone as params.

eg.

```
getCustomerData(Phone_Number: any) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/orders/getcustomer`, { params: { phone: Phone_Number } });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting error .....

 return res.send({ status: 0, data: result.recordset });
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recordset')